# Денормализация данных?

Tags: нейронные-сети, нормализация-данных

У меня вопрос насчёт НС, подскажите, как понять какое действие программа должна выполнить по значению из выходного слоя?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что значит: `"выполнить по значению из ..."`? вы можете переформулировать ваш вопрос? И причем здесь денормализация?

Comment: @MaxU ну вот смотрите что у нас является результатом нейронной сети, число [0..1], правильно?

Comment: да, правильно ... если вы активируете выходной слой сигмоидом...

Comment: Так вот, у меня есть допустим 4 действия, которое может быть выполнено: шаг вперёд, налево, вправо и назад. Так вот как понять,  что значит например 0.42, какое это действие из 4 ?

Comment: чем отличается вперед и вправо? что такое 0.42? вы можете сформулировать развернутый, полноценный вопрос?

Comment: Есть машина, есть 4 функции : газ вперёд, тормоз, повернуть руль влево, вправо, а так же есть нейронная сеть, которая выдаёт значение [0..1]. Так вот вопрос, как мне связать управление машинной и выходное значение НС [0..1]?

Comment: Ответить на этот вопрос невозможно не зная на что и как вы обучали вашу НС...

Comment: @MaxU ну я подстраиваю весы с помощью Генетического Алгоритма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если допустим у вас есть 4 действия, которые могут быть выполнены: шаг вперёд, налево, вправо и назад, то и выходов должно быть столько же. Т.е. 4 нейрона на выходе, каждому нейрону соответствует действие. Посмотрите, например, информацию об активации softmax, с её помощью вы получите на выходе вероятности. Т.е. нейрон получивший наибольшую вероятность указывает на действие соответствующее ему.